# Can I make an Enchantment table which can enchant to higher levels then 30?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft 1.9, End Cities spawn in the End. These End Cities contain Chests with various items, some of them enchanted. On the wiki I found out that the items may be enchanted to a random level from 20 to 39. By that they mean the level you enchant on in an Enchantment table (**not** Sharpness 30).

**Can I get/give myself an Enchant table with a higher maximum enchantment level? If yes, how?** I would really want it for my super-experimantal "survival" world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, it's impossible to enchant to higher levels than 30 on an enchantment table. In fact, it's only possible to get items enchanted with higher levels in the End Cities.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is **not possible** in minecraft any more, the only way would be, that you check if the player entchants something and put a higher entchantment level on it and take levels from him. But you would have to check for each item type and each entchandment combination.

Answer (score 2):

No, sadly you can't. There are mods that allow you to make a special enchantment table with special and unique enchantments, but back in the days in the beta of Minecraft you could enchant with way more levels and you can use the /echant command.

Comment: Btw with the /enchant command you can only enchant to the levels of a enchantment table. To get higher enchantments you can use the /give command and add some NBT data to the item (could be any item). Here is a very good command generator that you can use to generate the give comand: https://mcstacker.bimbimma.com/
I hope I helped you! Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Yes if only pure tools(or weaker, if you can list all possible tool existance that need to distingish) are allowed.

For example, to enchant a diamond sword with 35 levels:

1. check whether it's a diamond sword `testfor ...` and user has 35 levels `testfor @s[lm=35]
2. remove the user 35 levels `xp @s -35L`
3. remove the item to enchant `kill`, `setblock`, etc.
4. summon a dying mob which will drop/place a loot chest that contain, a diamond sword with level-35 enchant, using loot table

   {
       "pools":[
           {
               "rolls":1,
               "entries":[
                   {
                       "type":"item",
                       "name":"diamond_sword",
                       "functions":[
                           {
                               "function":"enchant_with_levels",
                               "treasure":false,
                               "levels":35
                           }
                       ]
                   }
               ]
           }
       ]
   }

EDIT: To do such enchant to non-pure and too-many-possibility tools, as long as it's same tool, you can get a such tool enchanted and copy its enchantment to your tool `execute if entity @e[tag=ench,limit=1,nbt={Item:{tags:{ench:[{id:32,lvl:1}]}}}] run enchant @s <32> 1`

Comment: Wow! Nice idea! Could you elaborate on point 4 please? I'm not completely familiar with 1.13 command syntax and loot tables.